# A Mosasaur With Gills?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology

What if a bunch of mad scientists genetically engineered a mosasaur like creature, but with gills so it doesn't have to surface. Let's say it would be about 60-80 feet long. Would the gills be placed behind its head like a fish, or would it be better (or worse off) if it had gills on the outside, like on its back like a sea hare?

Comment: Given that I can argue this in all the directions on offer I'm going to have to VTC as Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: A mosasaur is, anatomically speaking, a giant snake. Think of an anaconda scaled up. With gills, it would be a different creature, say a giant eel.

Comment: Since all tetrapods descended from fish, it'd imagine it would be like a fish. There's a reason why a [predatory] 60-foot fish has never existed, so don't be surprised if your 60-foot Mosasaur with gills still manages to drown.

Answer (score 11):

For battling subs you don't want a mosasaur.  It is going to lose its teeth in the metal and it wont be able to open its jaws wide enough to bite the hull.  Not to mention back engineering gills in an air breather will eat your entire evil science budget.

No, you want
**GIANT BATTLING BUMPHEAD FISH.**
[image: giant battling bumphead fish]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0dk5PeEs_Q

It has gills so there is that.  And a scary glare.  But for battling subs: these big fish accelerate to ram speed and bash into the side of the sub, caving in huge dents.  That is a fine way to attack a sub and a fine use of the kinetic energy of the fish.  It has a bump built to bash which your bumpologists will augment scientifically.  Bonus: it is a parrot fish!  Once it bashes in a dent it will go after the meta creases and those hardy nipper plates can pull and cut bits of metal off.

Comment: You always come out with original ideas

Comment: While this is a great and sensible idea, I'm pretty sure my readers will hate me if I put in a giant parrot fish as the "monster" lol.

Comment: @jtriptych - depends on how you write it, I’d think.  If you are taking it seriously, likely they will as well.

Comment: @jtriptych - I love the idea of a risible (waiting to use that word!) monster showing up, being mocked and then dishing out an unholy asswhupping.